# Arrays.copyOf(arr, 5); why cannot change the lenght of array

Tags: java

```
int[] arr = {2,6,8,4,5,7}; 
    System.arraycopy(arr, 3, arr, 2, 3);
    Arrays.copyOf(arr, 5);
    System.out.println(arr.length);
    for(int i= 0;i<arr.length;i++){
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
```

the result is 6
2
6
4
5
7
7

so you can see this function are not valid;

Comment: You shouldn't assume a library function is bugged. Rarely will you ever be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check out the source code

```
public static int[] copyOf(int[] original, int newLength) {
    int[] copy = new int[newLength];
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
                     Math.min(original.length, newLength));
    return copy;
}
```

the code `Arrays.copyOf(arr, 5);` doesn't change the length of origin array, it will return a new array with the given length.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't assigning the result of the copy. This

```
Arrays.copyOf(arr, 5);
```

should be

```
arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, 5);
```

assuming you want the first `5` elements from `arr`.

Comment: suppose there a issue in `System.arraycopy()` referring to the same `arr`